# How to add object attributes in array from another array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Firstly I have an array of multiple objects `[#<Vgpop::Game:0x00007fcd5b246a00 @name="Super Smash Bros. Ultimate", @console=nil, @score=nil>....]`

Then I have an array of my consoles that looks like this: `["Nintendo Switch"...]`

How do I map the values from my second array to my object array so that the return is:
 `[#<Vgpop::Game:0x00007fcd5b246a00 @name="Super Smash Bros. Ultimate", @console="Nintendo Switch", @score=nil>....]`

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: May want to consider modeling what you want to do before asking. It seems you have lists of items called games and game_consoles where the index corresponds to the current game and current game console. Seems really simple to iterate and use game[0].console = game_consoles[0]. Again if this is what you are asking then I recommend modeling what you want to do first as this is not ruby specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we can come up with this solution my friend:

```
first_array.each_with_index { |vgpop, i| vgpop.name = second_array[i] }
```

Comment: Well that is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: So, could you please mark my answer is right answer and vote it, sorry but I need some reputations to use adding comment feature.